# Selecting the first child without knowing the type of the first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="foo">
   ...
   <span> ---> can be the first
   <h1> ---> can be the first
   <h2> ---> can be the first
   and so on...
   ...
</div>
```

I want to add some CSS styles to the first element but without declaring what type the HTML element is.

For example, this piece of code will NOT help me:

```
.foo span:first-child
```

I want CSS that will work on the first element even if the developer will choose to make changes inside that div.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `.foo > *:first-child`?

Comment: .foo :nth-child(1) is another option

Comment: @Alex Maybe `.foo > :nth-child(1)` but only if you want to drop IE8 support.

Comment: yes I forgot a space, my bad. Didn't know for IE8 support, but thanks for the info.

Comment: You can also use use comma's like this: `.foo > div:first-child, .foo > h1:first-child, .foo > h2:first-child {...}` This doesn't answer your question though.

Answer (score 9):

You can just add this CSS, which will target any element which is the first child of `.foo`.:

```
.foo > :first-child {
    /* styling here */
}
```

Comment: Where `*` can also be omitted.

Comment: there is no need of *

Comment: Was going to post this fiddle but hey, you were faster ^^". http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/bjv7er5v/ **EDIT :** Removed the `*` from my fiddle

Comment: don't want to be a killjoy but we should really try to save space on servers by avoiding jsfiddle or others platform code editing for such little pieces of code ... only my opinion.

Comment: I doubt it used a whole lot of space @Alex

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** there are many ways to achieve this:

```
.foo > :first-child {
    /* Your Styles */
}

.foo > :first-of-type {
    /* Your Styles */
}

.foo > :nth-child(1) {
   /* Your Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.foo > *:first-child
{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
   ...
  <h2> ---> can be the first another</h2>
   <span> ---> can be the first</span>
  
   <h1> ---> can be the first</h1>
   
   and so on...
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.foo>*:first-child {
    /*style here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS 2.1 defines the [selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#selector-syntax) like this:

> A *simple selector* is either a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#type-selectors) or [universal
>   selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector) followed immediately by zero or more [attribute
>   selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors), [ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors), or [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes), in any
>   order. [...]
>
> A *selector* is a chain of one or more simple selectors separated by
>   combinators. Combinators are: white space, ">", and "+".

<sup>Note: The terminology in CSS3 is a bit different.</sup>

So your simple selectors must always begin with a type selector or a universal one. When you don't know the type of the element you want to match, use the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector):

> The universal selector, written "*", matches the name of any element
>   type. It matches any single element in the [document tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#doctree).

However, in this case the universal selector is not alone, there is also the `:first-child` pseudo-class. So you can omit the `*`:

> If the universal selector is not the only component of a [simple
>   selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#simple-selector), the "*" may be omitted.

So that simple selector will be one of those (they are equivalent):

```css
:first-child
```

```css
*:first-child
```

And the full selector will be

```css
.foo :first-child
```

```css
.foo *:first-child
```